# CScart pages won't load on shopfront website

Tags: php, cpanel, cs-cart

trying to troubleshoot a problem I'm having with a shopfront website. Two days ago the site was working fine, and then randomly all the links that are attached to the storefront (cscart) stopped loading with a fatal error. Any idea what could be going on? I contacted my host (a small orange) and it doesn't look like they updated their php in the last two days but that's all i can think of. They haven't been able to give me any useful information so I wanted to try here.

The homepage that works is : https://piercedtin.com/
But anything attached to the CScart shopfront is dead : https://piercedtin.com/cscart/about-our-company/
https://piercedtin.com/cscart/customizing/
https://piercedtin.com/cscart/tin-punch-kits/

The fatal error I received on load is as follows -

The error code is as reads:  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Tygh\get_magic_quotes_gpc() in /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php:218 Stack trace: #0 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php(193): Tygh\Bootstrap::setConstants(Array, '/home2/punchedt...') #1 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/init.php(27): Tygh\Bootstrap::initEnv(Array, Array, Array, '/home2/punchedt...') #2 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/index.php(24): require('/home2/punchedt...') #3 {main} thrown in /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php on line 218

Any information would be greatly appreciated. I'm a young guy so my familiarity with this sort of hosting is limited. Thanks for taking the time to read.

-Rums

Tried changing PHP through PHPmanager with no luck.

Error_log states:

[19-Nov-2023 19:31:22 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 181 in /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Shippings/Services/Usps.php on line 496
[19-Nov-2023 19:31:22 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 182 in /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Shippings/Services/Usps.php on line 496
[19-Nov-2023 19:31:22 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 100 in /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Shippings/Services/Usps.php on line 496
**[21-Nov-2023 02:40:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Tygh\get_magic_quotes_gpc() in /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php:218
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php(193): Tygh\Bootstrap::setConstants(Array, '/home2/punchedt...')
#1 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/init.php(27): Tygh\Bootstrap::initEnv(Array, Array, Array, '/home2/punchedt...')
#2 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/index.php(24): require('/home2/punchedt...')
#3 {main}
thrown in /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php on line 218
[21-Nov-2023 02:41:37 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Tygh\get_magic_quotes_gpc() in /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php:218
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php(193): Tygh\Bootstrap::setConstants(Array, '/home2/punchedt...')
#1 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/init.php(27): Tygh\Bootstrap::initEnv(Array, Array, Array, '/home2/punchedt...')
#2 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/index.php(24): require('/home2/punchedt...')
#3 {main}
thrown in /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php on line 218
[21-Nov-2023 02:41:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Tygh\get_magic_quotes_gpc() in /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php:218
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/app/Tygh/Bootstrap.php(193): Tygh\Bootstrap::setConstants(Array, '/home2/punchedt...')
#1 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/init.php(27): Tygh\Bootstrap::initEnv(Array, Array, Array, '/home2/punchedt...')
#2 /home2/punchedt/public_html/piercedtin/cscart/index.php(24): require('/home2/punchedt...')
#3 {main}**

The error that killed the site started on the 21st in the log above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.